# Intent-filter with two actions and categories

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Is it good to have such `intent-filter`? Maybe there is a better way to do it?

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<data android:mimeType="rext/plain"/>
```

I have Default Activity not found app running error is this case

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<data android:mimeType="rext/plain"/>
```

In the previous versions 2nd option worked good for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would split this into 2 intent filters i.e.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```